# I can't press more than one key while playing with my new keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I've recently bought a new keyboard, a Mars Gaming MK3, because my previous keyboard wasn't working very well (it was very old). Everything was good but when I decided to start playing a game I realized that there was a problem with the keyboard. It doesn't allow me to press more than one key at the same time.

For example, if I'm playing a shooter, I can't press A and S to move back and left, or I can't press S and R to move back and reload. It seems that it's the same problem for all keys combinations. Other things, like shortcuts (Ctrl + C, Win + R...), work well, so I don't know where's the problem.

I'm sure this can't be a hardware problem, because my previous keyboard was an older version of this one, a Mars Gaming MK2, and I didn't have these problems with it. Any help with my problem?

Comment: When you say the previous keyboard wasn’t working very well what do you mean exactly I had the same keyboard for a decade and it performed the same the entire time I had it

Answer (score 0):

Those are classic signs of ghosting, which gaming keyboards are supposed to at least *reduce*. I recommend returning it and picking something else.

Comment: In the keyboard specs it says that it has anti-ghosting, so i don't understand anything :(

Comment: i don't know what did i do, but now it works XD